# Kernel Panic after Fedora 19 Update

Tags: fedora, kernel, kernel-panic, freeze

After installing updates on Fedora 19 (kernel 10.3.7-200.fc19.x86_64) the DE freezes whenever I log in. Using the virtual consoles doesn't work.
One time I even got this kernel panic:

[image]

I have other kernels to try (10.3.5 and 10.3.3) and on them I don't get the freezes or the kernel panics.

Can you help me?

Comment: You should file a bug report. Looks like a bug in the bcrm80211 drivers.

Comment: how? sorry for my small knowledge...

Comment: Is there no way I can undo the kernel upgrade?

Comment: You can remove the kernel package if you still have other working kernels available. You can find instructions for filing a bug report [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bugs_and_feature_requests?rd=BugsAndFeatureRequests).

Comment: how would I remove the kernel package? yum remove pkgname? I obviously can do tty before I log in (grafically).

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously a unfixed bug with the broadcom wifi driver.
I reported the problem and did

```
sudo yum remove kernel-3.10.7
```

Now I'm on the old kernel and waiting for the fix to come.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998080